# POSTing data into remote mysql database returns 404 error but fetching works fine (Android and codeigniter)

Tags: php, android, mysql, codeigniter, retrofit

I'm able to read data from mysql database but when I try to insert data from android retrofit POST method, I get 404 not found error as response. Url is valid since it works well in postman. So I can't pinpoint if it's retrofit error or server error.
My retrofit POST method is

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("device")
Call<GcmCallback> registerDevice(@Field("gcm_registration_id") String gcm_registration_id);
```

Here is part of Okhttp log

```
06-08 00:30:50.626 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: --> POST http://example.com/news/index.php/Api/device HTTP/1.1
06-08 00:30:50.626 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
06-08 00:30:50.626 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 174
06-08 00:30:50.626 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: gcm_registration_id=d1i5nLhxIuA%3AAPA91bHg4KT4UDLyiSLL1YNgXG6eWrlpXIrbrZJr2Dv2lJXo4ClJo7MzjrBFcAX04vGISQjxIWbz23kg6Snm-PGO_VGElzubAEiQ9dgU1n9rM6rN1zx4QCWYyzEndY64aUhHKfgdzP9A
06-08 00:30:50.626 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: --> END POST (174-byte body)
06-08 00:30:51.074 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: <-- 404 Not Found http://example.com/news/index.php/Api/device (448ms)
06-08 00:30:51.074 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: Date: Tue, 07 Jun 2016 21:30:51 GMT
06-08 00:30:51.074 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
06-08 00:30:51.074 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
06-08 00:30:51.074 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 1190
06-08 00:30:51.074 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
06-08 00:30:51.074 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
06-08 00:30:51.074 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
06-08 00:30:51.074 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1465335050679
06-08 00:30:51.074 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1465335051074
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: <!DOCTYPE html>
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: <html lang="en">
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: <head>
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: <meta charset="utf-8">
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: <title>404 Page Not Found</title>
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: <style type="text/css">
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: ::selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: ::-moz-selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: body {
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     background-color: #fff;
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     margin: 40px;
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     color: #4F5155;
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: }
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: a {
06-08 00:30:51.075 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     color: #003399;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     background-color: transparent;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     font-weight: normal;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: }
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: h1 {
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     color: #444;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     background-color: transparent;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     font-size: 19px;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     font-weight: normal;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     margin: 0 0 14px 0;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: }
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: code {
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     font-size: 12px;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     background-color: #f9f9f9;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     color: #002166;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     display: block;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: }
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: #container {
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     margin: 10px;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: }
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: p {
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     margin: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: }
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: </style>
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: </head>
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: <body>
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:     <div id="container">
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:         <h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp:         <p>The page you requested was not found.</p>    </div>
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: </body>
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: </html>
06-08 00:30:51.076 24470-25616/com.aroniez.dailypaper D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (1190-byte body)
```

On top of that, while my code was on localhost, everything was fine but once I upload to remote server the problem starts.

Comment: you're not posting to mysql. you're posting to a php script. mysql can not EVER return a 404, because that's an http-level error, and mysql is not a webserver. that means the url you're posting to doesn't exist, and that by itself has nothing to do with mysql.

Comment: Check the user permissions

Comment: @MarcB well the url do exist because when I use postman for the same posting, everything works well.

Comment: @Tom let me double check permission issue.

Comment: well, the server can lie about 404. saying "doesn't exist" instead of "access denied" is rather stupid, imho, but security by obscurity is a powerful drug.